# Spring Core version update for ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

I want to update the spring-core version of ActiveMQ 5.15.12 from 4.3.26 to 5.2.3, i.e.:

```
org.apache.activemq-5.15.12_1/lib/optional/spring-core-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar
```

Once I change the Spring version I'm not able to start the ActiveMQ.

```
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: java.io.IOException: Could not load xbean factory:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/BeansException
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: java.io.IOException: Could not load xbean factory:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/BeansException
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:91)
```

Please help on how to update the Spring version.

Comment: You cannot just upgrade a version, you would need a newer version of ActiveMQ as well due to API incompatibilities.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thank you. But my task is it to update the spring-core version due to security issue but the latest ActiveMQ version 5.16.0 has the spring-core version 4.3.26